# stringBuilder.append("string") - unrechable statement

Tags: java, android

an easy one why this is wrong?

```
 public class SingleTouch extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String mensaje = ("el estado del tuch es: ");
        TextView text;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        text = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(text);
        text.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v ,MotionEvent event) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    //Line throwing error
                    builder.append("anything");

                    break;
                   }
       }
```

on the line marked appears (unrechable statment)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line to the end of the `onTouch` method:

```
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

Since this instruction is the first to be executed in your method, the rest of the code will never be reached.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v ,MotionEvent event) {
    switch() ....
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using "return" when invoking method from super class.

```
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should edit onTouch like this

```
public boolean onTouch(View v ,MotionEvent event) { 
    switch (event.getAction()) { 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        builder.append("anything");
        break; 
    } 
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```